# AS3/Flash Game Dev: Looking for good & current step by step

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Flash tutorials and examples have been around so long it is hard to know what sites to actually read for good, current AS3 game dev.

I'm looking for a good start to finish for flash game development, covering things such as:

Preloader (when to use, how to implement)
UI (AS3 only, no FLEX)
OOP architecture.  (I come from C++/C# world)

I'm just trying to create a simple game, sort of an "escape the room" style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/) and also the [Actionscript forum](http://www.actionscript.org/). They helped me a lot when I was a beginner. Also you might find useful the numerous tutorials and source code provided from [GotoAndPlay](http://www.gotoandplay.it). This is one site which made me interested into the gaming side of flash programming.

Comment: Found Actionscript.org to have some really good AS3 focused tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site: http://flashgameu.com/

I found those tutorials quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend the book "[ActionScript 3.0 Game University](http://flashgameu.com/)" which has many step by step tutorials for all genre of games (puzzle, match-3, platform, maze, shooter). His site is also full of examples not in the book. One of the better books out there (though there aren't really many game development books for AS3).

A new edition of the book seems to be on the way.

Comment: I've read that book.Its good for learning concepts.

Comment: I just noticed the video podcasts.  I once again will have something to watch on the subway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a Flash-Game-Framework such as [FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.net/) or [Flixel](http://flixel.org/), I suggest you have a look at the [Flash Game Dojo](http://flashgamedojo.com/). It's not a very extensive site, but a good place to start.

Comment: i don't think starting a game career with game engines like flixel and flashpunk is good. They reduce your learning skill set.

Comment: To add on to the comment, once you have a good grasp of the language or API, a good framework helps to let you focus on the game instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Kongregate's ["Shootorials"](http://www.kongregate.com/labs) (shooting tutorials) are second to none! They walk you through the process of creating a side-scrolling space shooter from start to finish (they even provide all the assets!). The tutorials were originally written for AS2, but they do provide a link to the AS3 source code [here](http://cdn2.kongregate.com/assets/files/0000/1183/shoot-as3.zip), and a mobile version written in AS3 [here](http://cdn2.kongregate.com/assets/files/0000/1420/shoot_mobile.zip). I found that going through the tutorials and looking at the AS3 source code was enough for me to understand what was going on, so I'm sure you'll be able to pick it up in no time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need 2 things: the first one is this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948 and the second one is - lot of beer. Furthermore you want to learn about flash events and events handling, display list model and drawing api. When you re done with that you can take a tour in collision detection principles, sprites animation, orthogonal and isometric projection methods unless you want to go 3D. After all that learned you are fine to go, not meaning you can't learn in progressing thriugh your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While this question is a little old now http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/ seems to be exactly what you are after.